# RIA Services does not submit when Application Exiting

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

We have a Silverlight application that needs to save some data just before the application exits. We are using RIA services, and implement the IApplicationLifetimeAware interface. We see the SubmitChanges method get called, but never see the callback (see pseudo-code below). Also, we see that there is never any request sent over the wire when we call SubmitChanges. Is there any way to do this?

```
public class ApplicationLifetimeMessenger : IApplicationService, IApplicationLifetimeAware
{
    private DomainContext context;

    public void Exiting()
    {
        context.SubmitChanges(OnSubmitCompleted);
    }

    private void OnSubmitCompleted(SubmitOperation op)
    {
        // Never gets here
    }

    // Other interface methods
}
```

Comment: maybe keep a while loop alive while the `DomainContext.HasChanges` is `true`

Comment: If I have a loop, the application just hangs. There is never a submit request sent over the wire, so the domain context always has changes.

Comment: Ok, well then there is only the suggestion of as the user clicks close, before even the ApplicationLifeTimeMessenger gets called, there can be no changes to the Context. Because you are dealing with async calls. If you have allot of changes, it can take a while before it returns.

Comment: That makes sense, but it would be extremely useful to be able to 'fire and forget'

Answer (score 0):

try using submitoperation.

```
SubmitOperation so = Context.SubmitChanges();                  
so.Completed += new EventHandler(so_Completed);
```

Comment: This doesn't work - the submit request is never sent over the wire, so the Completed event never fires. I'd guess that this approach is just a longhand way of writing context.SubmitChanges(so_Completed)?